# JSON parsing error while filtering JSON data inside a <script> tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've collected the JSON data within a script tag such as:

`<script>window.__APOLLO_STATE__ = {...some JSON data here...}<\script>`

However, while parsing, it shows the following error message:

Parse error on line 1:
...null,"meterPost({\"postId\":\"40d2d0d
-----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'undefined'

The first step is to collect page data using requests and BeautifulSoup:

```py
headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
        })
link = "https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2"
request_link = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
request_content = BeautifulSoup(request_link.content,'html.parser')
```

Now, when I directly copy the value of `window.__APOLLO_STATE__` from the output of `request_content` in Jupyter Notebook, and paste it in an online json-viewer, it works fine. But, I cannot work that way, right? I'll have to collect it. So, I tried to do so using the following code:

```py
def json_response(content):
    for tag in content.find_all('script'):
         if 'window.__APOLLO_STATE__' in tag.text:
              data = tag.text
    return data[26:]

json_data = json.loads(json_response(request_content))
```

However, the value of `json_data` doesn't work in the online JSON viewer and shows the parsing error. What's missing here? And how to solve the problem so that it can be saved in a JSON file?

Comment: Can't reproduce the error, your code runs fine..

Comment: first use `print()` to see what text you try to parse. maybe you cut off too much chars or you forgot cut off some char.

Comment: maybe you shouldn't conver string `data` to `json_data`. `json_data` is python structure, not JSON. `data` is JSON. And you should save `data` in file, not `json_data`